# Обернуть элементы в div внутри цикла WP_Query

Tags: php

Есть сайт на WordPress. Вывожу записи через `WP_Query`, подскажите пожалуйста как обернуть все `<div class="home_tn_link">` в один общий `div`, что бы этот общий `div` был на одном уровне вложенности с `<div class="title">`.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
] );
global $post;
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
            $fl = mb_substr( $post->post_title, 0, 1 );
            if( $fl !== ( $last_fl ?? '' ) ){
            $last_fl = $fl;
            ?>
                <div class="title"><?php echo $fl; ?></div>
            <?php
            }?>
            <div class="home_tn_link"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></div>
    <?php 
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Пример нужной структуры:

```
<div> 
   <div class="title"><?php echo $fl; ?></div>
   <div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div> 
   <div class="title"><?php echo $fl; ?></div>
   <div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div> 
   <div class="title"><?php echo $fl; ?></div>
   <div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
      <div class="home_tn_link"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, Вы хотите объединить home_tn_link в общий div? У Вас же сейчас идет title и за ним home_tn_link. Как Вы его хотели отделить, можете пример показать чего хотели бы добиться?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Спасибо, что отписали. Дополнила вопрос.

Comment: Верно понимаю, что сначала все title, а потом в отдельном div все home_tn_link?

Comment: @Denis640Kb нет, сначала один title, потом уже в отдельном div все home_tn_link, и так далее по циклу

Comment: Постарался дополнить ответ, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Я верно Вас понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял Вас, спасибо за уточнение. Исправил ответ
 Добавил общий тег, в котором title и второй раздел и для home_tn_link во втором разделе.

Постарался добавить комментариев. Проверьте, пожалуйста, я верно Вас понял?

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( [
    'orderby'        => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
] );
global $post;
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $MainDiv = ''; // То, что планируем выводить
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $fl = mb_substr( $post->post_title, 0, 1 );
        if( $fl !== ( $last_fl ?? '' ) ){
            $last_fl = $fl;
            $MainDiv .= ($MainDiv == '')?'':'</div></div>';  // Если строка уже заполнялась, и это новый title, то необходимо закрыть предыдущий тег div, сначала объединяющий home_tn_link, затем закрываем сразу тег ообщего блока, в котором title и блок с home_tn_link
            $MainDiv .= '<div><div class="title">'.$fl.'</div><div>'; // Если первая строка, то открываем div в котором будут title и блок с home_tn_link и сразу после title еще один div, в котором будут home_tn_link

        } else {
            $MainDiv .= '<div class="home_tn_link">'.$post->post_title.'</div>'; // Добавляем в общую переменную home_tn_link
        }
    }
    echo $MainDiv; // Выводим переменную общую на экран.
}
```

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли. Еще раз дополнила вопрос

Comment: Нет, структура совсем не та. Новый общий div (где должны быть все home_tn_link) пустой. Пропадает первый home_tn_link, а остальные home_tn_link идут отдельно от общего div.

Comment: @Анна 2 строчки MainDiv надо поменять местами.

Comment: Нужно просто убрать else в вашем ответе и все заработает ) Спасибо!